# Can I draw n rectangles using FOR loop in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, paintcomponent, repaint

How can I use or replace the code down below using for-Loop to draw size (25 * 25) rectangles in Java?

```
if (drawRectangles == 1) {
    graphics.fillRect(430, 428, 25, 25);
}

if (drawRectangles == 2) {graphics.fillRect(430, 428, 25, 25);
    graphics.fillRect(460, 428, 25, 25);
}

if (drawRectangles == 3) {
    graphics.fillRect(430, 428, 25, 25);
    graphics.fillRect(460, 428, 25, 25);
    graphics.fillRect(490, 428, 25, 25);
}

if (drawRectangles == 4) {
    graphics.fillRect(430, 428, 25, 25);
    graphics.fillRect(460, 428, 25, 25);
    graphics.fillRect(490, 428, 25, 25);
    graphics.fillRect(520, 428, 25, 25);
}
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`for` comprehensions are an integral part of many languages.

Tutorial for Java: [docs.oracle.com/../tutorial/../for](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Look for regular increments, loops are ideal for this.

You increment your `x` by 30 each time.

```
for(int inc = 0; inc  < drawRectangles; inc ++){
    x = 430 + (30 * inc)
    ...
    graphics.fillRect(x, y, x_size, y_size);
}
```

Consider using variables for things that are static. It makes your code more intuitive and makes it far easier to update and maintain.

Comment: Its work Perfectly thank you so much sir Im just beginner student its helped a lot.